# [GROOVY][SoapUI] Get part of a Soap Response to put it in an other Request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I've looked for a solution to this issue but nothing worked since. I'll explain to you.

I have two methods to call to udpate an adress, the first one give me datas in the response that I  need to call the second one. So I Tried the "Transfert Property" of SoapUI but, the thing is that put prefixes in the nodes that I've got from the response.

And the server can't handle prefixes in the second request for this datas. I tried to parse with XMLParser but same issue, prefixes...

So I've found that getting the nodes and their childs as text and put them as a string in a test case property will work as I need but I don't know which groovy methods I need. :'(

I want to get the XML structure and content defined in the "WhatIWantAsText" node,

Thanks for your Help ;)

```
<Enveloppe>
  <Node1>My Node1</Node1>
  <Node2>
     <Node3>Node3</Node3>
     <Node4>Node4</Node4>
     <WhatIWantAsText>
         <Child1>Child1</Child1>
         <Child2>
           <Child3>Child 3</Child3>
           <Child4>
               <Child5>Child5</Child5>
               <Child6>
                  <Child7>Child7</Child7>
                </Child6>
                <Child8>Child8</Child8>
          </Child2>
    </WhatIWantAsText>
  </Node2>
  <Node5>Node5</Node5>      
</Enveloppe>
```

Comment: Please specify input xml and output xml.

Comment: Hi @Rao, I'm pretty sure that you're already trying to help me from the smartbear forum but if it's not you, thanks btw. ^^ Here is the response from which I need to get all the protag structure as text (obviously with all the datas and childs inside ^^): http://dpaste.com/0C2ATRQ I'm would like to put it in a test case property named Protag in this request: pastebin.com/G7qVn56u Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The target is the protag property in this request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clas="ClasseMutwebServ" xmlns:xsi="xsi" xmlns:xsi1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
  <clas:ObjUpdateAdresseByType>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <clas:protag>${#TestCase#Protag}</clas:protag>
     <clas:pTypeAdr>PR</clas:pTypeAdr>
     <clas:pDateEffet>2018-06-01T00:00:00</clas:pDateEffet>
  </clas:ObjUpdateAdresseByType>
```